# JQuery Mobile Grid behavior different between local and JSBin

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

*EDIT: This turned out to be caused by nbsp's in the source HTML. I'm leaving the question up in the hope it might help someone else solve the same problem.*

JQuery Mobile's grid feature is not working correctly when I serve it locally or even open it as a file.

The test code I've pasted at the bottom of this message works correctly in JSBin. The blocks line up with no vertical offsets. Here's the JSBin link and a link to an image of the output.

http://jsbin.com/bocubeqaza/1/edit?html,output

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxFySp3qjVxxUkgzeUpBME9kcW8/view?usp=sharing

Serving the file locally, however, produces a vertical offset in the right most element of each group of blocks.  Here's a link to the output from the code (which has no local dependencies) when viewed locally.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxFySp3qjVxxVkZ3czFacTdJOWM

(Sorry for the image links; SO's imgur uploader doesn't like google drive links and I don't have an alternate public location for screen grabs)

I've tried the obvious things like clearing the browser cache and restarting it. Moreover, the misbehavior is reproducible when I serve it from my desktop and view it on my phone (Android, Chrome browser).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />        

    <title>Sandbox</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial-scale=1.0>


    <!-- STYLESHEETS -->    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/git/jquery.mobile-git.css"> 

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/git/jquery.mobile-git.js"></script> 
  </head>
  <body>

    <div data-role="page" id="sandbox">
      <div data-role="content">

        <div style="background: grey;">Foo</div>
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:60px">Block A</div></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:60px">Block B</div></div>
        </div><!-- /grid-a -->
        <div style="background: grey;">Bar</div>
        <div class="ui-grid-b">
            <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:60px">Block A</div></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:60px">Block B</div></div>
            <div class="ui-block-c"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:60px">Block C</div></div>
        </div><!-- /grid-b -->
      </div>


</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In case it's helpful, there's also an issue I opened at the JQMobile site this morning: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/8501 .  They responded quickly but closed the issue since it wasn't reproducible in JSBin.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Forgot to mention, the ui-grid blocks are taken verbatim from JQ Mobile's demo pages.

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassingly, this turned out to be caused by nbsp chars. They got into my code when I pasted the Grid examples from JQ Mobile Demos and my editor wasn't configured to show them (it is now!).  Compounding the matter, it appears that JSBin helpfully scrubs them from pasted HTML -- which explains why the code worked there and not locally.